# How to return two or more column values originating from an inner array?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a table that has a CLOB JSON column with a compressed JSON. Inside this JSON, I have two XML, as below:

```
{
    "type": "com.xpto.abc.impl.JobResponse",
    "data": {"responses": {"666a3c3f-666-45cb-aa50-666930b42fd7": ["XML1", "XML2"]}}
}
```

Using SQL, how I can get the XML1 and XML2? I tried to use the below query. It is working fine to retrieve the nodes "type" and "data", but does not work to iterate into XML1 and XML2.

```
select tipo,
       seq,
       response
from   response r,
       json_table(r.payload, '$'
       columns tipo  VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.type',
               responses  varchar2 FORMAT JSON PATH '$.data.responses[*]',
               NESTED PATH '$[*]' 
                 COLUMNS (seq FOR ORDINALITY,
                          response VARCHAR2 FORMAT JSON PATH '$'));
```

I want the following query return:

| TIPO | SEQ | RESPONSE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| com.xpto.abc.impl.JobResponse | 1 | XML1 |
| com.xpto.abc.impl.JobResponse | 2 | XML2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```sql
select tipo,
       seq,
       response
from   response r
       CROSS APPLY
       json_table(
         r.payload,
         '$'
         columns
           tipo  VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.type',
           NESTED PATH '$.data.responses.*[*]' 
           COLUMNS (
             seq FOR ORDINALITY,
             response VARCHAR2 PATH '$'
           )
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE response (
  payload CLOB
          CHECK( payload IS JSON )
);

INSERT INTO response ( payload ) VALUES (
'{
    "type": "com.xpto.abc.impl.JobResponse",
    "data": {"responses": {"666a3c3f-666-45cb-aa50-666930b42fd7": ["XML1", "XML2"]}}
}'
);
```

Outputs:

> | TIPO | SEQ | RESPONSE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | com.xpto.abc.impl.JobResponse | 1 | XML1 |
> | com.xpto.abc.impl.JobResponse | 2 | XML2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=29a7299161616b3812b55094720c1205)*

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!